# How to get all Products in Orderhive API

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Orderhive new version of API -> https://orderhive.docs.apiary.io/#reference/product/product-catalog. According to documention, the size can be added in the URL but when I tried this one I am having bad request error.

I have tried these below and all of them same error "Bad Request":

https://api.orderhive.com/product/listing/flat?size=500

https://api.orderhive.com/product/listing/flat?size=1000&page=1

Tried this and it is working however I can only get 20 products
https://api.orderhive.com/product/listing/flat
[image]

How can I query into the next page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://orderhive.docs.apiary.io/#reference/product/product-catalog/product-catalog

`default` `size` is 20 & max size is 1000

Sample call in C# is like below. You can change URI & `StringContent` in content as parameter as required:

```
//Common testing requirement. If you are consuming an API in a sandbox/test region, uncomment this line of code ONLY for non production uses.
//System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

    //Be sure to run "Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http" from your nuget command line.
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;

    var baseAddress = new Uri("https://private-anon-c49488141a-orderhive.apiary-mock.com/");

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient{ BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {

      httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("authorization", "AWS Signature Headers(check in above Authentication flow)");

        using (var content = new StringContent("{  \"types\": [    \"7\",    \"1\"  ],  \"qty_ranges\": [    {      \"min\": \"1\",      \"max\": \"2\",      \"warehouse_id\": \"\",      \"key\": \"available_qty\"    }  ],  \"date_ranges\": [    {      \"min\": \"1560760921\",      \"max\": \"1560769921\",      \"key\": \"modified\"    }  ],  \"query\": \"nike\"}"))
        {
          using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("product/listing/flat?size=500", content))
          {
            string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I am having forbidden error when endpointUri = https://api.orderhive.com/product/listing/flat?size=100&page=1 then var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpointUri);

Comment: Have you changed URI for base address & provided correct auth ?

Comment: Forbidden means path/resource is correct but some issue in authorization. try `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };` before call  if you are in some sandbox environment

Comment: I can get the products with the URL = https://api.orderhive.com/product/listing/flat but when I add parameter to url like this https://api.orderhive.com/product/listing/flat?size=100&page=1 that where an error forbidden occurs

Comment: try removing `&page =1` if that works then you can add filters inside post data

Comment: Already tried removing the page=1 and also adding it to post data but still the same error. If I remove both size and page and add those in post data, I can get 20 Products the default even if I set the size to 100

Comment: Can't find `page` as param in documentation, completely remove `page` & try with size & other param